# Cannot create a new account

Tags: nodeos, accounts, mainnet, account-creation

I've just installed an EOS node on my Ubuntu VPS, and it seems be working well. Sync speed is pretty fast also.
I ran nodeos like:

```
nodeos --genesis-json eos_data/config/genesis.json --config-dir eos_data/config/ --data-dir eos_data/data/
```

I've also created a new wallet, two key pairs and imported them to the wallet. Then I've imported the key pair for eosio account as well.
So when I execute `cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:5801 wallet keys`, all 3 public keys are displaying.

```
[
"EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV",
"EOS7YnvWfj************************************************************",
"EOS7uBeu8*************************************************************"
]
```

Then, I've unlocked the wallet.
So I thought that is sufficient to create a new account.

Unfortunately, when I tried the following:

```
cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:5801 create account eosio NEW_ACCOUNT owner_public_key active_public_key
```

it displayed an error:

```
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"eosio","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
```

I am not sure what's wrong and how I can fix this problem.

Do I need to finish synchronization before creating new accounts?

Comment: Have you changed the pair of key of `signature-provider` option in `config.ini`? If then, you should add that private key to your wallet. Check what keys are used in `eosio@active` permission. (`cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:5801 get account eosio` in your case)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to indicate the permission after the transaction. You have to add at the end:

`-p eosio`

So that the full command looks like:

`cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:5801 create account eosio NEW_ACCOUNT owner_public_key active_public_key -p eosio`

Comment: Still the same error when I appended "-p eosio".

Comment: Is the eosio private key part of your nodeos setup?

Comment: What's that? How can I add the private key of eosio to my nodeos?

Comment: --private-key '[ "PUBLIC KEY", "PRIVATE KEY"]'

Comment: Did you mean the line in config.ini?    signature-provider = EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV=KEY:5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3

Comment: No I meant add it on command line when you type in nodeos

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.From your information, you ran nodeos like:

> nodeos --genesis-json eos_data/config/genesis.json --config-dir eos_data/config/ --data-dir eos_data/data/

1.1 this node is not a producer as no **-p** specified;

1.2 this node have no chain-plugin, so it will not accept you cleos request, and say "**Error 3110001: Missing Chain API Plugin**";

1.3 the default port is **127.0.0.1:8888**.

#### 2. You create account use this command

> cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:5801 create account eosio NEW_ACCOUNT owner_public_key active_public_key

so you call other node to create account, not the one you mentioned.
You can check the eosio account info by

> cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:5801 get account eosio

and see the public_key of eosio, and check whether is in your wallet.

The **eosio** account key is based on the genesis.json, **not** the config.ini or --private-key or signature-provider.

Other producers's key is based on that:

- signature-provider
- private-key
- config.ini